# С# проблема с получением текста из richboxtext который находится в tabpages

Tags: richtextbox

Я пытаюсь создать блокнот со вкладками. и при попытке сохранить вкладку не могу взять текст из richtextbox  который находится в TabPage

```
private void newTabPage(object sender, EventArgs e){
            //path = string.Empty;

            TabPage new1 = new TabPage("Нотатка" + count);
            new1.Name = "Нотатка" + count;
            RichTextBox tb = new RichTextBox();
            tb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            tabControl.TabPages.Add(new1);
            new1.Controls.Add(tb);
            tabControl.SelectedTab = new1;
            count++;

        }


private async void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path)) 
            {
                using (SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog() { Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*", ValidateNames = true })
                {
                    sfd.FileName = tabControl.SelectedTab.Text;
                    if(sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sfd.FileName))
                        {
                           RichTextBox richtextbox = new RichTextBox();
                           richtextbox.Name = tabControl.SelectedTab.Text;
                            await sw.WriteLineAsync(richtextbox.Text);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: измените заголовок - это русскоязычный портал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не совсем понимаю чего вы хотели достигнуть используя:

```
RichTextBox richtextbox = new RichTextBox();
richtextbox.Name = tabControl.SelectedTab.Text;
```

Таким образом объект не получит ссылку на другой объект.Вы просто одному из свойств присваиваете другое значение.

Один из способов получить ссылку на этот объект:

```
RichTextBox richtextbox = Controls.Find(tabControl.SelectedTab.Text, true).FirstOrDefault() as RichTextBox
```